# Triangle inequality with convergent sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $|x _n|,\ |y _n|,\  |z _n| \le 1$, prove that 
$$
\sum _{ n=0 } ^{ \infty } \frac {| x _n - z _n|} { 2^n } \le \sum _{ n=0 } ^{ \infty } \frac {| x _n - y _n|} { 2^n } + \sum _{ n=0 } ^{ \infty } \frac {| y _n - z _n|} { 2^n }
$$

One can see that each term, in each sum, is bounded by $2/2^n $, but I don't get further than that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The hypothesis about the absolute values is superfluous.

Comment: Consider the partial sums, and then take the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series of nonnegative terms converges to the supremum of its partial sums. Since $$|x_n - z_n| \le |x_n - y_n| + |y_n - z_n|$$ for all $n$ you get $$\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{|x_n - z_n|}{2^n} \le \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{2^n} + \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{|y_n - z_n|}{2^n} \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{2^n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|y_n - z_n|}{2^n}$$ whether or not the right hand side is finite. Now let $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Ok, simple, but thanks!